# Capture content after function is called

Tags: php, html, profiling

Is it possible (in PHP) to call a function that triggers some capturing process so all HTML output after that function is captured up until an ending function? For example, some profiling applications do very similar procedures to this, and with functions such as    `ob_start()`, it seems logical to me.
Example of concept:

```
<?php beginSection("hello"); ?>
<b>Hi there!</b>
<?php endSecton("hello"); ?>
<!-- Section "hello" now contains "<b>Hi there!</b>" -->
```

Comment: Erm yes, you can do exactly that with `ob_start`, so if you know that already - what is the question?

Comment: @Niels I was unaware what the actual function of `ob_start` was. At the time, I thought that all it did was capture output from including a file.

Answer (score 2):

The way output buffering works does not allow you do this in a named fashion - `ob_start` and its friends *stack* on eachother, and unwind in order. You could implement it like this:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<b>Hi there!</b>
<?php $sections['hello'] = ob_end_clean(); ?>
```

This would answer your question.

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware the ob_* functions worked for raw HTML as well as included files as I was oblivious to how the function worked.